# Reach hosts using FQDN and their hostname only without FQDN

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

please help:

Is it possible to set up a static inventory so that hosts are accessible using their FQDN, as well as hostname without putting to Ad-hoc or playbook hosts full FQDN?

For example inventory file:

```
[production]
production1.local.domain
```

And commands:

```
ansible production1 -m ping
ansible production1.example.com -m ping
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. Each entry must be declared. For example

```
production1 ansible_host=production1.local.domain
production1.local.domain

[production]
production1

[production_fqdn]
production1.local.domain
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! Is this the only way to solve the problem?

Comment: Inventory must comprise `production1`  If `ansible production1 -m ping` should work. The same is valid for `production1.local.domain`. What other solution would you expect?

Comment: Something like inventory_hostname_short var but specially for inventory? So be it. There are no more options I think.